# I want to pushback and change but my code first changes

Tags: c++

Hello everyone Im working on a project but Im stuck in a point.
I am trying to write a code that stores a char into a string then change the char to '_'. But my code changes the char first and gets that char to my string how can I fix it?
Sincerely

`word.push_back(puzzle[x++][y]);
            puzzle[x++][y] = '_';
            puzzle[x--][y];`

In this part of code puzzle is the main matrix that I want to use and word is the vector that stores my characters.

Sorry if I couldn't explain myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
word.push_back(puzzle[x][y]);
puzzle[x++][y] = '_';
```

The problem with your code was that it incremented `x` before you changed the char to `'_'`. Obviously you should only do that afterwards.

Comment: I dont want to change my string to _ I want to change a char of my matrix (puzzle) to _.  Think a 3x3 matrix that includes chars, I want to push back the char in (0,1) to my word vector. Then change the char in puzzle matrix to _.

Comment: My main code is kinda long but and I havent explain all. I tried yours but it failed
Vector subscript out of range

Comment: @KürşatSaimTUNA Well that's because your `x` and `y` values are wrong. I can't help with that unless I see more code.